# Linking to video within website on two different pages

Tags: html, css

I want to know how I can link to a video using a thumb of a image from one page to another.

For instance if I wanted to link to the page only from one page to another I would simply put

```
<img src="theotherpage.html" />
```

But that doesnt quite do the job for me. I need to link to the video directly. 
How can I do that?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, you wanto to link to the video file, or embed the video on the website?

Comment: create a snapshot of the video to create the image, then user the solution as pointed by YardenST

Comment: @Chevi I have already embedded the videos, but on another Page. Now I want to link to the videos from yet another page consisting of links displayed in image thumbs of the videos from the Main page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the image with `<a>` tag

```
<a href="link-to-direct-video">
   <img src="image-thumb-src" />
</a>
```

If I understand your question correctly.

Comment: But if I use an anchor tag, how specific can I be? Because I need a link to a video on another page in the same website. Do you understand??

Comment: @DinoExcel you can link to every valid url. if the url is on the same website, you can give a relative url (href="videos/food/1.mov"...)

Comment: I think the issue lies in the page I am linking to. When I click on a video in that page, It doesnt trigger any change in the URL field in my browser, so probably it works differently. It is actually a plugin, for videos... So I am not sure how it works.'

Comment: @DinoExcel you can open another question to ask how to communicate with this plugin

Answer (score 1):

If you want to link to a page with one video, use [YardenST's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14041996/1262824). If you want to link to a page with many videos, but you want to scroll to that video you can use an anchor.

On the videos page, say you have the following HTML:

```
<div id="video1"> ... </div>
<div id="video2"> ... </div>
```

If you wanted to link to the second video, you could use

```
<a href="/videos.html#video2">
    <img src="image-thumb" />
</a>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesnt work. I added an id to the video I wanted to link to, inside the anchor tag, and then I used that id on my anchor tag in the image thumb... But it only redirects to the page...

Comment: If you link as I said, using ´#{ID}´ will always make the browser scroll to the location of the element with that ID. Ensure that only one element has that ID